# Manipulate sqlite databases without html5 browsers

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to create a client side app in javascript that downloads a sqlite database off a server and allows the user to modify it. This app needs to be all client side though, and can't rely on features only present in firefox for example. Is there any framework you are aware of that provides these features?
(Perhaps emulated of sorts?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: Javascript, by design, cannot access local machine files.  If it's okay to keep the db server-side and have the client interact with it, the server can execute queries and updates to the DB based on what the client asks it to do (a la web service).  This is true for HTML5 browsers as well.

Some browsers, such as firefox and chrome, come with packages that will allow the browser to talk to sqlite dbs, but they are not written in javascript and can do things that javascript cannot, which is why they are included as browser-specific packages instead of as js scripts.

Comment: You couldn't even modifiy sqlite dbs by using localstorage of some kind on the client (like cookies?)

Comment: Cookies have an extremely limited length.  I doubt you could store any sort of db in them.

Comment: Not cookies specifically, but just an available cache for random stuff used by a site

Comment: @BraunShedd What cache is that? That's what the HTML5 is for--that capability didn't exist before.

Comment: @Dave Didn't know that was HTML-5 only, guess I'll have to roll with a Pusher powered solution (kind of suggested by Bdares)

Comment: @Braunshedd Bdares just suggested a normal webapp; that's pretty much your option if you want it cross-browser and not an app :/